# Dynamic id name in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this code to add class and remove attribute,but the problem is that I have dynamic id name who depends from row id. I try with `'#ee'+x` but doesn't work. Please help, how can I set dynamic value in jQuery

```
$('#ee').change(function(){
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('#we').addClass("hide");
        $('.re').removeAttr('checked');
    }
    else {
        $('#we').removeClass("hide");
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the actual name of the `id` and where is `x` coming from? It might help to post some of the HTML.

Comment: The way you show (`$("#"+some_string)`) should work.

Comment: If you know the row id, just use `.next()` or `.find()` or some similar function to navigate to the element dynamically from its parent.

Comment: When I set these and add multiple div with same id script only works for first div

Comment: You shouldn't have more than one element in the DOM with the same id. Use classes for that.

Comment: What has PHP & MySql got to do with this problem?

Comment: @idor_brad Using classes is problematic if you're performing jQuery or Ajax on a single element. Classes would be the wrong answer.

Comment: @AlxVallejo It's not valid html to have the same ID for multiple elements, which is what the OP mentioned in the comment above mine. If you're trying to wire the same event up to multiple elements, which I believe is the case in this question, you should use classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('[id^=ee]').change(function(){
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('#we').addClass("hide");
        $('.re').removeAttr('checked');
    }
    else {
        $('#we').removeClass("hide");
    }
});
```

You could try this, it's using [css3 substring matching](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings).

Edit:
Just did a quick test, css3 sub-string matching seems to work in jQuery 1.8.2, as seen in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hm34g/

Answer (score 1):

I would use a class instead:

```
$('.someClass').change(function(){
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('#we').addClass("hide");
        $('.re').removeAttr('checked');
    }
    else {
        $('#we').removeClass("hide");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your requirements is this :

If we want to hide the row, the checkbox in that row should be checked. If yes, then,
you can add this code :

```
   $(this).parent().parent() // chain like this till you get the required row
```

If checkbox is present in td of tr, then above works .